# PostgreSQL & division_by_zero exception

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I can't quite get this right.. my function looks like:

```
create or replace function myfunc(integer, varchar(25), varchar(25), integer, integer) returns numeric as $$
declare var_return numeric;

begin

select sum(a+ b) / sum(a + b + c)
from mytable
where col1 = $1
and col2 = $2
and col3 = $3
and col4 between $4 AND $5
into var_return;

exception when division_by_zero then return 0.0;

return coalesce(var_return, 0.0);

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

But when I do `select myfunc(123, 'foo', 'bar', 1, 10);` I see:

```
ERROR:  control reached end of function without RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "myfunc"
```

Why does this happen? Clearly I want to catch when the `select` statement encounters a case where `a + b + c` equals 0 and return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXCEPTION clause pertains to the entire BEGIN block, and runs until the END.  That is, Postgres understands you to have written this:

```
create or replace function myfunc(...) returns ... as $$
  declare var_return numeric;

  begin
    select ...
    into var_return; -- but no RETURN statement in this block
  exception when division_by_zero then
    return 0.0;
    return coalesce(var_return, 0.0); -- this is part of the exception handler
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Move your "RETURN COALESCE..." above the EXCEPTION line, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can vastly simplify your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(int, varchar(25), varchar(25), int, int)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$

SELECT CASE WHEN abc = 0 THEN 0::numeric ELSE (ab/abc)::numeric END
FROM (
    SELECT sum(a + b) AS ab, sum(a + b + c) AS abc
    FROM   mytable
    WHERE  col1 = $1
    AND    col2 = $2
    AND    col3 = $3
    AND    col4 BETWEEN $4 AND $5
    ) x;

$BODY$ language SQL;
```

#### Major points

- This is `language SQL`, not a PL/pgSQL function. You can use either, but for a simple case like this you might as well stick with the simpler tool.
- @pilcrow diagnosed the cause of your error accurately. The way you have it, the `RETURN` statement is part of the exception handler and is only ever reached if an exception occurs.
- If the data type of `a, b, c` should be `integer` or `bigint`, you probably want to cast to numeric *before* the division or the results will be coerced to integers.
- Use a `CASE` statement to avoid division by zero. This is **much** cheaper than exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you handle the right exception ?

I guess that you have another exception.

[See a list of exception you can trap.](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/postgresql/vol1/PostgreSQLErrorCodes.html#SEC377)

I would try first ( I always put exceptions at the end of the block, easier to read.)

```
create or replace function myfunc(integer, varchar(25), varchar(25), integer, integer) returns numeric as $$
declare var_return numeric;

begin

   select sum(a+ b) / sum(a + b + c)
   from mytable
   where col1 = $1
   and col2 = $2
   and col3 = $3
   and col4 between $4 AND $5
   into var_return;

   return coalesce(var_return, 0.0);

   exception 
      when division_by_zero then 
         return 0.0;
      when others then 
         RAISE NOTICE 'caught others';
         return 0.0;



end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: The OP is trapping the right exception, but the RETURN statement was in the wrong place.

Comment: @pilcrow Yeah, I just realize that. I try his code but hard-coding a division by 0. The exception was caught properly even if the return was below the exception block. His code works only if he has a division by 0 :-)